# Django NoReverseMatch - is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, paypal, model, django-views

I am following [this](https://overiq.com/django-paypal-integration-with-django-paypal/) tutorial to integrate PayPal into my website.
It works perfectly and I am really happy with the concepts I have learned thus far.
However, I would also like to integrate a subscription service which is explained in the [**second tutorial**](https://overiq.com/django-paypal-subscriptions-with-django-paypal/), but I am stuck at this part.

First, there is a typo I believe in the 'subscription' function at this line:

```
    return render(request, 'ecommerce_app/subscription_form.html', locals() <-- missing closing ')'
```

Second, I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /process_subscription/
'payment' is not a registered namespace
```

When I navigate to http://localhost:8000/subscribe/ and fire the subscribe button.

If anyone is able to figure out what I am missing here or can get this issue fixed for me is highly appreciated :)

p.s. I am just a Django beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 'payment' as app_name in your app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import YourSubscribeView

app_name="payment"

urlpatterns = [
    path('subscribe/', YourSubscribeView.as_view(), name="subscribe"),

]
```

Comment: adding app_name="payment" to app/urls.py gives the following: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: can you please post your app urls.py file

Comment: Thank you for your replies sir, https://pastebin.com/jGdr7QFm

Comment: urls.py is fine, check in your template, it should be like this, {% url "payment:index" %}

Comment: Reverse for 'process_subscription' not found. 'process_subscription' is not a valid view function or pattern name. I added `payment:` everywhere. Please see my repo:  https://github.com/reindersbioinformatics/tmp and see contact info

Comment: you have to change in your views too like in templates. Change this: return redirect('process_subscription') to return redirect('payment:process_subscription'),
Similarly check others too.

Comment: I feel like we're almost there. new error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /process_subscription/
payment:process_subscription please see the repo and see contact info in the readme :)

Comment: In your process_subscription view correct it with this:return render(request,'ecommerce_app/process_subscription.html',locals())

Comment: Thank you so much sir! WORKS :D

Comment: If you think my answer help you, please upvote comments and answer, also accept it.:) Happy coding !!